# psql cmd command specify password (through java application)

Tags: java, postgresql, cmd, passwords, psql

Can I include the password to my psql command?

My command is:

psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U mee -d my_db -f sqltest.sql

because I'm trying to run it through my java application but i didn't know how to specify it.

```
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U mee -d my_db -f sqltest.sql");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeere : "+line);
```

Comment: Well, did you take a look at the [`psql` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html)?

Comment: yes. I found that  -W force the user to insert the password, but i diddn't  really get the point of -w. should I insert the password in pgpass file so i will not be obliged to insert it in the cmd?

Comment: Well, not thoroughly enough. There is the possibility of passing password through an environment variable, or through a connection string (instead of database name), or, as the answer mentions, using `.pgpass`. All of this information is reachable through the documentation.

Comment: If you do not want to store the password outside of your application: [Connection URIs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING). For example: `psql -d 'postgresql://mee:secretpassword@localhost:5432/my_db' -f sqltest.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most you can do is save the password for the user you are connecting through in `.pgpass` file - [located in a user's home directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html). This way psql will not ask for the password. There is no way to pass password as an argument with psql.